# Docker container not able to connect to remote MongoDB

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, docker, flask

I have a `flask` based python code which simply connects to `mongodb`.It has two routes `Get` `Post`. `Get` simply prints `hello world` and using `Post` we can post any json data which is later saved in `MongoDB` This python code is working fine. `MongoDB` is hosted on cloud.

I have now created a Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6-alpine3.7

RUN pip3 install pymongo

ENV LISTEN_PORT=8000
EXPOSE 8000

COPY /app /app
```

Using command to run

`docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000 myflaskimage`

After starting the container for this docker image, I am getting response of `GET` but no response from `POST`. I am using `Postman` software to post json data. I get below error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No servers found yet
```

I am bit confused as to why the python code is working fine but when I put the same in docker and start container, it throws error. Do we have to include anything in `Dockerfile` to enable connections to `MongoDB`.

Please help. Thanks

Python Code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)

def connect_db():
    try:
        client = MongoClient(<mongodbURL>)
        return client.get_database(<DBname>)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def main():
    db = connect_db()
    collection = db.get_collection('<collectionName>')

    @app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
    def data():
        j_data = request.get_json()
        x = collection.insert_one(j_data).inserted_id
        return "Data added successfully"

    @app.route('/')
    def hello_world():
        return "Hello World"

main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Comment: Where is mongo running? Can the container connect to it? What hostname do you use there?

Comment: @Thilo `MongoDB` is hosted on cloud.When running just the python code and doing Post on localhost, everything is working fine but doing same from container side, it shows error. How do I check if container is connected to mongo.?

Comment: can you start a shell into the container and use the `mongo` command-line client?

Comment: @Thilo I tried it and run the `mongo` command line clinet, but it says not found may be because in the `Dockerfile` I have just installed `pymongo` which is python module for mongodb. Is there any other way I can try the connection to mongodb from within the container

Comment: Are the container and your local environment using the same version of `pymongo`?

Comment: Yes local environment and same version of pymongo

Comment: Where and how, if you spun up the service yourself, are you hosting mongodb?

Comment: Mongodb is running on azure cloud. I have its ip address and port which I am using in python code for connection. Running the code everything works fine. But doing the same from docker, it do not work.

Comment: Can you add more information; e.g. logs from the container, debug what MongoClient says etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have internet connection from the container. I had a similar issue when connecting from containerized java application to public web service.

At first I would try to restart docker:

```
systemctl restart docker
```

If it does not help then look into resolv.conf in you container:

```
docker run --rm myflaskimage cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

If it shows `nameserver 127.x.x.x` then you can try:

1) on the host system comment `dns=dnsmasq` line in */etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf* file with a `#` and restart NetworkManager using `systemctl restart network-manager`

2) or explicitly set DNS for docker adding this into the */etc/docker/daemon.json* file and restarting the docker:

```
{
    "dns": ["my.dns.server"]
}
```